# PHP SoapClient: How to pass complex-type parameters to a webservice?

Tags: php, soap, multidimensional-array, namespaces, complextype

I'm having trouble passing nested array parameters while accessing a SOAP-Service from a PHP Application.
I found several threads regarding this issue, but none of them solved my problem.
So I hope someone can help me out here...

I'm using PHP 5.4.22 on an xampp for windows installation and trying to access the Talentlink API. Its WSDL is defined here:

https://api3.lumesse-talenthub.com/CareerPortal/SOAP/FoAdvert?WSDL

The access generally works fine. WSSE-Authentication works, I can access data from the service.
I can pass parameters to the Soap-Methods as too, as long as they are in a flat structure and defined as basic- or simpletypes:

```
$this->criteria = $service->getCriteria(array(
    'lovOrders' => '1,2,12,13',
    'langCode' => 'DE'
));
```

so far so good.

My problem shows up, when I try to pass a complex-type parameter as an array.
I'm trying to access the getCriteria function, which has the following definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="getCriteria">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="langCode" type="tns:langCode"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:searchCriteriaSorting"/>
    <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="lovOrders" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

[...]

<xs:complexType name="searchCriteriaSorting">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="categoryListsSorting" type="tns:criteriaSortType"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="customLovsSorting" type="tns:criteriaSortType"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="standardLovsSorting" type="tns:criteriaSortType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

[...]

<xs:simpleType name="criteriaSortType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="LABEL"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="ORDER"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

My problem is the "searchCriteriaSorting"-Parameter.
I am trying to pass it to the service-method it like that:

```
$this->criteria = $service->getCriteria(array(
    'lovOrders' => '1,2,12,13',
    'langCode' => 'DE',
    'searchCriteriaSorting' => array(
        'customLovsSorting' => 'LABEL'
    )
));
```

PHPs SoapClient generates the following SOAP-Request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getCriteria>
        <ns1:langCode>DE</ns1:langCode>
        <searchCriteriaSorting>
            <customLovsSorting>LABEL</customLovsSorting>
        </searchCriteriaSorting>
        <ns1:lovOrders>1,2,12,13</ns1:lovOrders>
    </ns1:getCriteria>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

As you can see, the parameter **"langCode"** and **"lovOrders"** are generated **with namespace prefix**, while the **"searchCriteriaSorting"** parameter is generated **without** it. But without the namespace prefix, the parameter is not processed by the Soap-API.

I can't figure out, why the namespace prefix is not generated for the complex type parameter.

I tried different approaches as well:

- array-to-object conversion
- the use of stdClass structures and SoapVars
- automated wsdl2php-classgeneration and using the "classmap"-parameter

However, I couldn't get any of these working properly.

Can anyone help me out here or at least push me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you solved the issue. I have the same problem. I tried all over the internet. It seems really few people work with SOAP and PHP.

Comment: Hi @KasunRajapaksha. As a matter of fact I did solve the problem. I can't access the code right now, but I will post a working example here soon.

Comment: Hi @Turbulenz . Appreciate. please put the code when possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://example.gms/test01/cims/services/1.2/travel.asmx?WSDL',array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

var_dump($client);

// $date=date()
$result= $client->$youre method Or Function(array('perameter1'=>"value1", 'perameter2'=>"value2"));  
print_r($result);        
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```